# Drush not reading config file from top-level /drush folder within Drupal install?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm trying to have localized *drushrc.php* configurations and alias configurations per site I'm working on, but no matter what I'm trying right now, drush refuses to find or load my *drushrc.php* configuration file.

Based on #2 in the example configuration file found here:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drushrc.php

I should be able to place a *drushrc.php* configuration file in a top-level /drush folder location:

- $DRUPALROOT/../drush/drushrc.php (top-level parent above root folder)

No matter what I'm trying drush never seems to detect the configuration file in this location when I do a *drush status* in the drupal root folder. Everything works fine if I place *drushrc.php* within my home folder (*~/.drush/drushrc.php*) or in a sub-folder of my install (*$DRUPALROOT/drush/drushrc.php). Problem is I don't want there and would like it in a top-level folder above my root install!

Is there a secret to getting drush working based on this ?! I've tried *drush cc drush* every time I move my configuration around but it's never found!

On Mac OS X if it matters? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is a typo in Drush preventing this:

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1542

This fix should be in the next version of Drush.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: ah okay! So it wasn't just me going insane then. Thanks!